# Why are different currents through the TVS diode or 8-20 us and 10-1000 us

Tags: tvs

In datasheet you can see that the currents are different.

[image]

For any TVS diodes, Ipp(8-20)> Ipp(10-1000). For an example, see datasheet [SM15TY](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/sm15ty-955284.pdf)

I do not understand why the current depends on the overvoltage time?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a link to the datasheet so we can get context.

Comment: Because the diode heats up while shorting that current. The longer the overvoltage is applied, the more heat it has to store before it can dissipate it. The latter is a very slow process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know very little about these but I found the question interesting.

A search for "transil application note" brought up [ST AN316](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/30/f6/d4/72/7d/74/45/bc/CD00003857.pdf/files/CD00003857.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003857.pdf).

[image]

*Figure 1. From the application note it appears that there are two standard test pulses used to test these devices. Note that the average current is taken as the time from the start to the 50% decay point - the second number in the 8/20 or 10/1000 specification.*

Reading on:

> **Transil peak power dissipation**
>
> One of the goals of the Transil is to protect equipment against transient disturbances. The
>   duration of these transients is linked to the application where the Transil operates. For
>   example electrostatic discharges (ESD) are in the range of tens of ns while industrial strikes
>   are within tens of µs, telecom over-voltages, hundreds of µs and automotive surges tens of
>   ms.
>
> The performance of the Transil are given in the datasheet for both 8/20 µs and 10/1000 µs
>   waves (VCL, IPP), otherwise the curve peak pulse power versus pulsed duration (see
>   Figure 3) allows the designer to choose the right Transil for his application.

There are some example calculations in section 5 of the AN. They might be worth a read. I haven't quite figured them out yet.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. I have seen the same notation (8/20 and 10/1000) in other components. I think SCR's. I guess is is somewhat common to spec pulses that way.